# Woocommmerce. Нужно вывести все метки, относящиеся к конкретной категории

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Возникла проблема при выводе меток для всех категорий. Есть код, но он выводит метки для текущего товара:

```
function woocom_tags_list(){
$output = array();

// get an array of the WP_Term objects for a defined product ID
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_tag' );

// Loop through each product tag for the current product
if( count($terms) > 0 ){
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $term_id = $term->term_id; // Product tag Id
        $term_name = $term->name; // Product tag Name
        $term_slug = $term->slug; // Product tag slug
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'product_tag' ); // Product tag link

        // Set the product tag names in an array
        $output[] = '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term_name.'</a>';
    }
    // Set the array in a coma separated string of product tags for example
    $output = implode( ', ', $output );

    // Display the coma separated string of the product tags
    return $output;
}
}
```

У меня есть id категории, нужно вывести все метки для нее и дочерних категорий. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Метки и категории никак не связаны между собой это 2 таксономии и они привязаны к посту

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_terms_in_term( int $term_id, string $term_slug, string $child_term_slug ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $key   = 'child_' . $child_term_slug . '_by_' . $term_id;
    $terms = wp_cache_get( $key );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
        return $terms;
    }
    //phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery
    $terms = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            'SELECT DISTINCT t.term_id as term_id, t.name as name
                FROM ' . $wpdb->terms . ' as t
                         LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' as tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
                         LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . ' as r ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
                WHERE tt.taxonomy = %s
                  AND r.object_id IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
                    FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' as p
                             LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . ' as r2 ON p.ID = r2.object_id
                             LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' as t2 ON t2.term_id = r2.term_taxonomy_id
                    WHERE p.post_type = "product"
                      AND p.post_status = "publish"
                      AND t2.taxonomy = %s
                      AND t2.term_id = %d
                )
                ORDER BY name',
            $child_term_slug,
            $term_slug,
            $term_id
        )
    );
    if ( $terms ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
            $terms[ $key ]->url = get_term_link( $term->term_id );
        }
        wp_cache_set( 'child_' . $child_term_slug . '_by_' . $term_id, $terms );
    }

    return $terms;
}

$terms = get_terms_in_term( 55, 'product_cat', 'product_tag' );
```